# Stopwatch glitches

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, stopwatch

I made a stopwatch application recently and it had a few glitches.

If I hit the stop button twice in a row, the entire app would crash.

If I hit the start button twice in a row, the timer would run twice as fast and the stop button would stop working.

How do I fix this problem?

Here is the code in my .h file:

```
    IBOutlet UILabel *time;
    IBOutlet UILabel *time1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *time2;

    NSTimer *myTicker;
    NSTimer *myTicker2;
    NSTimer *myTicker3;
}

- (IBAction)start;
- (IBAction)stop;
- (IBAction)reset;


- (void)showActivity;
- (void)showActivity1;
- (void)showActivity2;

@end
```

and here is my code in the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)start {
    myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  

    myTicker2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    myTicker3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];        
}

- (IBAction)stop {
    [myTicker invalidate];
    [myTicker2 invalidate];
    [myTicker3 invalidate];
}

- (IBAction)reset {    
    time.text = @"00";
    time1.text = @"00";
    time2.text = @"00";
}

- (void)showActivity {    
    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + 1;
    if (newTime == 60) {
        newTime = 0;
    }
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];     
}

- (void)showActivity1 {
    int currentTime1 = [time1.text intValue];
    int newTime1 = currentTime1 + 1;
    if (newTime1 == 10) {
        newTime1 = 0;
    }
    time1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime1];    
}

- (void)showActivity2 {
    int currentTime2 = [time2.text intValue];
    int newTime2 = currentTime2 + 1;
    time2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the stop button's `userInterActionEnabled` property to `NO` and the start button's to `YES` when the `-stop` method is fired.  Then switch and set the stop button's `userInterActionEnabled` to `YES` and the start button's to `NO` when `-start` is fired.

Comment: where is userInterActonEnabled?

Comment: It's a property of UIButton.  Like `self.myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO`;

Answer (score 1):

You should create a private BOOL variable "isRunning", which is checked when clicked on Stop or Start like:

```
- (IBAction)stop {
    if(!isRunning) return;

    [myTicker invalidate];
    [myTicker2 invalidate];
    [myTicker3 invalidate];

    self.isRunning = NO;
}
```

etc. Also ignoring user interactions is general a good idea (like CodaFi suggested), but only fights the symptoms ;-) You really should do both checks.

Comment: how do i create a private BOOL variable "isRunning"

Comment: Add this line to the @interface (where you also define your IBOutlets, NSTimers etc.): `BOOL isRunning`. That's it ;-)